# JSF Mojarra 2.3 in Wildfly 11

Tags: jsf, mojarra, wildfly-11

I'm having JSF application and have upgraded the mojarra version from 2.2.15 to 2.3.0 and found that restore view is taking more time than 2.2.15 version(attached the image).

We have enabled phase debug options in my application to find the details.

Wildfly Version: 11
Mojarra Version: 2.3.0

Note: Mojarra 2.2.15 is consuming 50% less than 2.3.0 version. my understanding is 2.3.0 is always taking more time to restore the view.

Mojarra 2.3.0

[image: Mojarra 2.3.0]

Mojarra 2.2.15

[image: Mojarra 2.2.15]

Comment: Can you try with Mojarra 2.3.5 https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.3.5? Checked the issue list of fixed issues?

Comment: After upgrade restore view performance is improved little i.e from 234 ms to 216 ms.

I have split javax-faces-2.3.5 jar into JSF-API.jar (Javax packages are grouped) and JSF-impl (com/sun packages are grouped).

Updated above JSF-API.jar in Wildfly (system/layers/base/javax/faces/api/ folder) and JSF-impl in (system/layers/base/com/sun/jsf-impl/) folders. If my setting is wrong please guide.